# Python. Отображение .!entry вместо текста

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Проблема заключается в создании программы программой, допустим я имею данный код:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox as mb
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

def clicked():
    system = open("system.py", "w")
    system.write('''
print("''' + str(API) + '''")
''')
    system.close()

root = Tk()
root.configure(background="#457f8a")
root.title("Tkinter")
root.geometry("300x400")

text = Label(root, text="Введите текст: ", bg="#457f8a", fg="#ffffff")
text.grid(padx=0, pady=0)
API = Entry(root, width=15, bg="#00d9ff")
API.grid(padx=0, pady=0)
button = Button(root, text="Готово", command=clicked, background="#30c9cf", height=2)
button.grid(padx=6, pady=6)

root.mainloop()
```

При выводе в **clicked** будет текст **.!entry**. Объясните как это исправить.

Comment: Очевидно, выводить не само поле, а записанный в него текст.

Comment: @sergey-gornostaev на примере можно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно вернуть содержимое `Entry` это можно сделать так:

```
system.write('''print("''' + API.get() + '''")''')
```